# Package hooks Error: Extra \PopDefaultHookLabel

Tags: miktex, texstudio, windows, hooks

Recently I moved from Mac to Windows and when I compile the document class nle.cls in Windows, which can be downloaded from this [link](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-file-manager/file/5d2c9092615ba8773a3a582f) (it is a journal template), I get lots of errors. I did not have this problem in Mac. I already installed Miktex and updated it and am working in TeXstudio or TeXworks. I doubt something is missing in my installed tex on Windows. Could someone please help me? Thanks.

```
\documentclass{nle}

\begin{document}
    write something
\end{document}
```

Log file:

> ! Package hooks Error: Extra \PopDefaultHookLabel. (hooks)
> This command will be ignored.
>
> Type  to continue.  ...
>
> ```
>                                                l.4044 \setlength
>              \dashlinedash{0.2pt}
> ```
>
> LaTeX does not know anything more about this error, sorry.
>
> Try typing  to proceed. If that doesn't work, type X 
> to quit.
>
> Runaway argument? @empty @expl@pop@filename@@ @reset@ptions \relax
> \setlength \dashlinedash \E TC. ! Paragraph ended before
> @p@pfilepath@aux was complete. 
> \par  l.4049
> I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this control sequence to too much text. How can we recover? My plan is to
> forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
>
> \belowmidrulesep=\dimen337 \midlightrulewidth=\dimen338 \figbox=\box94
> \figheight=\dimen339
> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/natbib\natbib.sty
> Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO) \bibhang=\skip182
> \bibsep=\skip183 LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694.
> \c@NAT@ctr=\count372 )
>
> ! Package hooks Error: Extra \PopDefaultHookLabel. (hooks)
> This command will be ignored.
>
> Type  to continue.  ...
>
> ```
>                                                l.4119 \bibpunct
>             {(}{)}{;}{a}{}{}
> ```
>
> LaTeX does not know anything more about this error, sorry.
>
> Try typing  to proceed. If that doesn't work, type X 
> to quit.
>
> Runaway argument? @empty @expl@pop@filename@@ @reset@ptions \relax
> \bibpunct {(}{)}{\ETC. ! Paragraph ended before @p@pfilepath@aux was
> complete. 
> \par  l.4132    \renewcommand\newblock{\par
> }% I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this control sequence to too much text. How
> can we recover? My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the
> best.
>
> ! Too many }'s. l.4132    \renewcommand\newblock{\par}
> % You've closed more groups than you opened. Such booboos are generally harmless, so keep going.
>
> ! Extra \else. l.4133  \else
> I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.
>
> ! Too many }'s. l.4141 }
> {% You've closed more groups than you opened. Such booboos are generally harmless, so keep going.
>
> ) ! Extra \fi.  ...op@@ }\expandafter @firstofone \fi
> l.2
> I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.
>
> ! Package hooks Error: Extra \PopDefaultHookLabel. (hooks)
> This command will be ignored.
>
> Type  to continue.  ...
>
> ```
>                                                l.2
> ```
>
> LaTeX does not know anything more about this error, sorry.
>
> Try typing  to proceed. If that doesn't work, type X 
> to quit.
>
> Runaway argument? @empty @expl@pop@filename@@ @reset@ptions
> @documentclasshook  ! Paragraph ended before @p@pfilepath@aux was
> complete. 
> \par  l.2
> I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this control sequence to too much text. How can we recover? My plan is to
> forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
>
> ! Extra \endgroup. \document ->\endgroup
> \ifx @unusedoptionlist @empty \else @latex@warning@... l.3 \begin{document}
> Things are pretty mixed up, but I think the worst is over.
>
> (test_file.aux) \openout1 = `test_file.aux'.
>
> \openout3 = `test_file.tab'.
>
> LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line
> 3. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3. LaTeX Font Info:
> ... okay on input line 3. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for
> OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input
> line 3. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input
> line 3. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3. LaTeX Font Info:
> Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 3. LaTeX Font Info:
> ... okay on input line 3. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for
> OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input
> line 3. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input
> line 3. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3. LaTeX Font Info:
> Trying to load font information for OT1+ptm on input line 3 .
>
> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/psnfss\ot1ptm.fd
> File: ot1ptm.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm. ) Overfull
> \vbox (42.0pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []
>
> Overfull \vbox (42.0pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
> []
>
> Overfull \vbox (702.46448pt too high) has occurred while \output is
> active []
>
> Overfull \vbox (31.65767pt too high) has occurred while \output is
> active []
>
> Overfull \vbox (670.60768pt too high) has occurred while \output is
> active []
>
> ! Undefined control sequence. \set@color ...@pdfcolorstack
> push{\current@color
> }\aftergroup \reset@color  l.5 \end{document}
> The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g.,
> `\hobx'), type` I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox').
> Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
>
> ! Undefined control sequence. \set@color ...@pdfcolorstack
> push{\current@color
> }\aftergroup \reset@color  l.5 \end{document}
> The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g.,
> `\hobx'), type` I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox').
> Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
>
> [1{C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
> (test_file.aux) )  Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:  3407
> strings out of 479618  43158 string characters out of 2865026  317756
> words of memory out of 3000000  20606 multiletter control sequences
> out of 15000+200000  407847 words of font info for 35 fonts, out of
> 3000000 for 9000  1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
> 68i,7n,74p,280b,175s stack positions out of
> 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
> {C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/enc/dvips
> /base/8r.enc}<C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/urw/time
> s/utmr8a.pfb> Output written on test_file.pdf (1 page, 10269 bytes).
> PDF statistics:  11 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)  0 named
> destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)  1 words of extra memory for
> PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)

Comment: @gernot you tested with a very old version of the class (from 2004), with the new version in the link I can reproduce the error.

Comment: the class redefines `\@pushfilename`, an internal command, and this breaks the new LaTeX hooks. They redefine \document which breaks latex too. Beside this they load etex which they shouldn't, (and they redefine \@outputpage which is dangerous too). All this should be reported to the class maintainer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks a lot for a quick reply. I commented out some of them and it does not give those errors anymore. I am just wondering why it was working without error on Mac. Do you think these issues are also OS-related?

Comment: your tex system on the mac is probably older, the hook system in LaTeX is rather new. But to be clear: they are changing internal and core commands, that is always in danger to break after some update. And if you undo some of their changes, it could be that you don't get the intended layout. You should really contact them.

Comment: @Mila can share the lines you have commented out.

Comment: @EngS I commented out the commands related to `\def\@pushfilename{`, 
`\def\store@outputpage{`, `\def\document{\endgroup`, and `\def\@outputpage{`.